# Interaction Level in EPUBs

Tags: epub

Is it possible to add some questions after each chapter in a epub and somehow restrict user not to move forward to the next chapter in the book until he has answered the end chapter questions.

I have seen a implementation and was wondering how did they achieved it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have access to Javascript to handle the end-of-chapter tests. Store the results in local storage. Then, when you're loading a page to which access might be restricted, consult local storage to see if the user is allowed to see it, and based on the result do something like adding a class to the body tag to display a non-accessible message:

```
<script>
    window.onLoad(function(){
      var can_access=get_accessibility(location.href);
      if (!can_access) { document.body.className="no-access";}
    };
</script>

#no-access-msg { display: none; }
body.noaccess #no-access-msg { display: block; }

<body>
  <div id="no-access-msg">You can't access this page yet, take the test first.</div>
```

You get the idea.